# Highlighting a part of a text using html

Tags: javascript, css, html

[image]

Hello everyone.
  The question which I have mentioned earlier is related to this. The letter which        is shown in image was written by using unicodes.
     పా
   now I want to highlight the white part of that image. I have tried this by replacing the required part by using
     ా but it is not suitable as it is having the dotted lines. And I even tried this by using the png image of that letter for which it is harder for me to change the colour of the image for highlighting. Please suggest me some methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a font, create a custom font from https://icomoon.io/. For that you will need SVG file of both the symbol `పా` and `ా` and create a font. that way you will be able to change all propeties of font using CSS.

Here is a tutorial on [How to Create a SVG from Illustrator](http://www.sitepoint.com/create-an-icon-font-illustrator-icomoon/)

Comment: ya, you need SVG files and you can create your custom font pack, like font awesome